# Most important const & rvalue refs

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++03 you can use the `const&` trick (or "most important const") to extend the lifetime of a temporary to the lifetime of the reference. My question is, in C++0x, does this behaviour extend to rvalue references? I.e `auto&& x = someFunction();`

Comment: Why do you need this? 'const auto&' does exactly the same job.

Comment: You could modify the temporary.

Comment: Actually if you look at move constructors that's exacty what they do. They bind to an rvalue and modify it.

Comment: The `auto&&` will also adjust automatically if `someFunction` returns an lvalue. Making the `auto&&` be an lvalue reference then.

Comment: @RedX: But passing a temporary to a function does not extend its lifetime. It will still be destroyed at the end of the full-expression.

Comment: Your initialization is wrong. In that case, `x` is always deduced to a reference to an `std::initializer_list<T>`: `auto` treats a braced initializer list specially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `[class.temporary]`, if that compiles then yes, the lifetime of the temporary is extended.

Comment: There is no explicit mention of rvalue references, though I suppose that that's implicit with the term "references". Makes me uneasy, though.

Comment: See §8.3.2/2: A reference type that is declared using & is called an lvalue reference, and a reference type that is declared
using && is called an rvalue reference. (...) Except
where explicitly noted, they are semantically equivalent and commonly referred to as references.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles perfectly on VC10 SP1:

```
int && Get()
{
    return 10;
}

const auto&& y=Get();
```