# Can auto using parens mean a function prototype?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, type-inference

This question arose from being unable to use uniform-initialisation syntax with the `auto` keyword because it treats it as a `std::initializer_list<T>` (explanation in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548486/most-important-const-rvalue-refs)).

Take the following code example:

```
class X { };
int x( X() ); // function prototype (1)
auto x( X() );  // copy/move construction of an X, function prototype or compile-time error?
```

What does the compiler do with `auto x`?

Reasoning for each possibility:

**Copy/move construction:** I can see this being the proper behaviour due to (1) being seen as a kind of defect.

**Function prototype:** Seems unlikely as there is no trailing return type.

**Compile-time error:** If the compiler does parse this as a function prototype, it may cause a compile-time error due to lacking a trailing return type.

What does the C++0x standard say this should be interpreted as?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get

```
error: 'x' function uses 'auto' type specifier without late return type
```

The compiler is expecting something like

```
auto x( X() ) -> int;
```

which would be equivalent to line 2.

Comment: That sounds consistent with the old C++98 behaviour, though, so that's a good thing. If you want to construct `x` from a temporary `X`, you should say `auto x((X()));`.